# Is it possible to require a connection string in the DbContext constructor, configured from DI (startup.cs) without IDbContextFactory?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, azure-functions

Apologies if this is confusing, my head is fried trying to find a solution,so my explanation may be terrible. Just pointing me in the right direction would be beneficial and I will clarify as needed. Most likely this may just be my lack of understanding DI. Thanks in advance!

I have a DBContext (EF6) in a stand-alone library that I share between two applications ... an ASP.Net Core 1.x Web site and an Azure web function (using azure functions core tools). Of course, these use different settings files, but that is another issue altogether. I do not want to use any "hard-coded" connection strings, so I tried to set up the DI to use the appsettings.json connection string:

```
var connectionString = connectionStrings.Data.App1.ConnectionString;
services.AddScoped<AppDbContext>(_ => new AppDbContext(connectionString));
```

I'm also using a generic repository that I have set up as:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
```

The repository works with a specific entity in the DBSet. A service is then used for each resource. The implementation of each service (which may be used in an MVC page or from an API endpoint) accesses the Repository. For example, the constructor for the Configuration service is ..

```
public AppConfigurationService(IRepository<AppConfiguration> repo)
```

registered as

```
services.AddScoped<IService<AppConfiguration>, AppConfigurationService>();
```

The constructor of the Repository accepts an instance of "AppDbContext" that I thought would use the connection string above.

```
public Repository(AppDbContext context)
```

While debugging, I noticed that the connection string is not always set. When  AppConfigureServices is executed ... the connection string is passed in as expected. However when a controller instantiates a service, the connection string is always empty, so the default DBContext constructor is called.

My home controller's constructor is set as

```
public HomeController(IService<AppConfiguration> service)
```

When I attempt to access the service's Repo from any of the controller's actions, a DbContext is newed up without the connection string.

Is it possible to set the connection string this sort-of way in startup.cs? Could my use of generic base classes be messing up DI? If I use IDbContextFactory, is there any way to determine if there is a connection string available for the DbContext before going to the config files?

Again thanks for any suggestions/direction pointing.

**Update**

Consider, The AppConfigurationService inherits from BaseService that is defined as follows:

```
public class AppConfigurationService : BaseService<AppConfiguration>
...
public abstract class BaseService<TEntity>: IService<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntityId<Guid>
```

Services that do not inherit from the BaseService, eg:

```
public class ConnectionService: IService<Connection>, IServiceClone<Connection>
```

Are newed up with a connection string. So, only the Services that inherit from BaseService do not have the connection string with the DBContext.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to setup you connection string as a singleton, since you have two separated applications sharering the same repository.

Something like this:

```
interface IConnectionProvider { string GetConnectionString(); }
public class ConnectionProvider : IConnectionProvider { public string GetConnectionString() { return connectionStrings.Data.App1.ConnectionString; } }

services.AddSingleton<IConnectionProvider, ConnectionProvider>();
```

Then modify you DbContext to receive the connection provider:

```
public AppDbContext(IConnectionProvider provider) : base(provider.GetConnectionString())
```

Hope that it helps.

Comment: Great thanks! I'll give that a try using IOptions and let you know the results.

Comment: Not a real change using IOptions, some calls still do not have a connection string while most do. The stack trace of the failing and working code has the same origin. If I find anything else out, I will let you know. Thanks for taking the time on this.

Comment: How are you instantiating your service on the controller that the string connection is coming empty? Do you get from DI or hard coded way?

Comment: So it is not really that the connection string is coming in empty in the controllers, that is always passed in. Something (internal, not a call I am making, hence the issues trying to debug it) is instantiating. Most of the time my "AppDbContext(string connectionString) base(connectionString)" gets called. On rare occasions, the default "AppDbContext()" constructor is instantiated. I can not always make it happen and once this happens in the controller, all subsequent calls have the connection string set. Though this controller is "public HomeController(IService<IrisConfiguration> service)"

Comment: That Service is instantiated as ... "public ConfigurationService(IRepository<IrisConfiguration> repo) : base(repo, AppTier.Application) {}" ... which looks like ... "public Repository(AppDbContext context, IMapper mapper) : base(context, mapper) { }"

Comment: Are you using the OWIN Architecture? Is Your DI library configured to use the context in the right way? Depending on library you are using, for each type of project it haves the own way to configure it. Another way to debug it is removing the default constructor from AppDbContext. If theres a place that is calling it, probably it will throws some exception and then you wil be able to trace it.

Comment: Sorry it has been awhile ... not using OWIN but I've reduced the amount of times that the context is instantiated through the services. It does not resolve the issue entirely and I still can not figure out what is calling the default constructor.